# requests.put() , rest api throwing bad request error on sending json in request body

Tags: python-3.x, rest, spring-boot, python-requests

Hi I am new to python and below is my code which calls a REST api :

```
    api_url = 'https://gateway.eu1-int.myproject.io/api/iottimeseries/v3/timeseries/1234/propertyname'
    payload =[{
       "_time": "2017-12-30T09:54:28.502Z",
       "FLWheel_qc": 1,
       "FRWheel_qc": 13,
       "RLWheel_qc": 55,
       "RRWheel_qc": 6
    }]
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    http_proxy = 'http://' + rest_client_config.proxy_host + ':' + rest_client_config.proxy_port
    proxy_dict = {
        "https": http_proxy
    }
    json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
    r = requests.put(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict)
    json_data = json.loads(r.text)
```

I have tried different combination in requests.put

```
    json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
    r = requests.put(api_url, data=json_payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict)
```

or:

```
r = requests.put(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict)
```

The rest api is developed using spring boot , I am getting the below error:

```
{'timestamp': '2018-11-03T12:36:09.585+0000', 'status': 400, 'error': 'Bad Request', 'exception': 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException', 'message': 'JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@664d6d8c; line: 1, column: 1]', 'path': 'api/iottimeseries/v3/timeseries/1234/propertyname'}
```

I am stuck with this since a long time. I have tried all the possible solutions I found. However exact same request is working from postman. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Seems your payload isn't the same JSON value that Spring Boot API receives. Did you try to do a request with Postman tool and you got the same error?

Comment: yes same exact thing are working from postman .

Comment: So with Postman tool is displayed that same error,   isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanJohx I m working on a sdk and the same api client has been developed in java and this works perfectly fine with postman. I am newly developing the client in python . So there is no error with the json body

Comment: Okay I think that you should remove this brackets  [ ]  because you are updating  a resource (PUT) so you don't have to pass a list but a JSON object and use this : r = requests.put(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict) let me know if it works.

Comment: @JonathanJohx api expects a list of objects, so removing [] wont work.

Comment: Okay, please remove data and put json with payload .    r = requests.put(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxy_dict)  you need to be in JSON context. @smruti ranjan

Comment: @JonathanJohx have tried doing that.. still getting the same error

Comment: I think the better way is to compare request and find out what the difference.